# class constructor and object instanciation/initialisation C++/GCC

Tags: c++, class, gcc, constructor

I have troubles with a C++ class constructor, using GCC.

The class "foo", hereunder, is supposed to emulate a processor register like AL, AH, AX, EAX,... and i need to have some basic arithmetic associated with this class.
but i have a strange behaviour in the initialisation or a "foo" object.

I don't have have the same result for the 2 following cases:

```
foo w=0x12345678; //  case 1

foo w ;           //  case 2 init ( 2 steps)
    w=0x12345678;
```

For me, case 2 is working
GCC calls foo() ( constructor 1) then the = operator. At the end, w.m_val is ok
But for case 1 GCC calls directly foo( long *) ( constructor 2) and nothing else. Obviously that's not what i'm expecting.

If "foo" where char , int or long, the result would be the same for both cases.

I maybe misunderstood something about constructors or did something wrong. Could somebody help me ?

Thanks.

```
class foo
{
    public:
        foo(){ // constructor 1 
          m_val=0;
          m_ptr=NULL;
          };

        foo(long *p){ // constructor 2, should never be called!!!
          m_val=0;
          m_ptr=p;
        };
        friend foo  operator+( const foo &rhs, const unsigned int v );

        foo &operator+= (unsigned int v )
        {
            m_val+=v;
            return *this;
        }

        ~foo(){};

         foo &operator= ( const foo &rhs )
         {
            m_val=rhs.m_val;
            return *this;
         };
         foo &operator= ( const unsigned int v )
         {
            m_val=v;
            return *this;
         };

    private:
        unsigned int m_val;
        long *m_ptr;
};
```

Comment: the problem is not in the posted code (as I write this). post a complete, minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I tried your code on a different compiler (Visual Studio 2010) and I got a compiler error on the line `foo w=0x12345678;` which is what I would expect. So either you have found a compiler bug (unlikely but not impossible) or you haven't posted your real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding something about constructors. Despite appearances, `foo w=0x12345678;` does not contain any calls to an assignment operator. It is *copy-initialization*, and (mostly) equivalent to:

```
foo w{foo{0x12345678}};
```

This should not compile, because `foo` does not have a constructor that takes an `int` parameter.

I say "mostly" because `foo w=0x12345678;` requires the existence of an implicit conversion from `int` to `foo` (or a subclass of `foo`), where `foo w{foo{0x12345678}};` involves an explicit conversion, and will never construct a subclass of `foo`.

Comment: foo has the 2nd constructor foo( long *) and this ctor is called in foo w=0x0123456;

Comment: @spamy: what compiler version/options are you using? For me, gcc produces a fatal error about invalid conversion on that line. Which is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: In that case your compiler has a bug. `0x0123456` is an `int`, and there is no way for an int to implicitly become a pointer.

Comment: Ok, but in may case the foo's object's are only singles object or objects belonging to parent's. That's why there are 2 constructors. So i have to create the either by foo w(&parent_object)=0x12345678 or foo w=0x12345678; but neither case, 0x124678 should be and address.

Comment: @spamy It would help if you were to post a *small complete program* that has the problem you are describing. Also since a compiler bug is possible, the version number and compiler options you are using.